# eps from Matlab .fig does not show axis and labels in Latex

Tags: eps, matlab

I would like to make clear from the start that I don't have the matlab script that produced these .fig, so answers concerning Matlab configurations might not give an answer (although accepted as future advice). In addition, the time pressure I have for my project is enormous.

I have almost 50 .fig produced from Matlab and their corresponding .eps files.

I am using Xelatex + subfiles package, Texmaker, MacTeX. The .eps files look GREAT when previewed as files. But when included and compiled in Latex, there are no axis or labels (or any font-related stuff). I looked around for solutions but most answers are suggesting matlab related modifications when producing the figure. Some also mentioned that if compiled in a different system under the same settings, the problem does not show up. That is why I guess a MWE won't be useful.

I do have Matlab installed if urgently needed.

> **EDIT**: I found out that the problem has to do with the font of matlab which is NOT set to interpreter: latex. If I go and change the
>   matlab figures' label property to `'interpreter','latex'`, it shows the
>   labels. But still, I have to deal with the axis and legends x49 more
>   figures :P

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite a lot of hours, **in a random check of the resulting pdf file, i realized that the eps images appear as expected** and very nice indeed. So, i don't want to jump into conclusions but the whole thing might have to do with TexMaker's pdf preview (of course related to a interpretation issue as mentioned above). If anyone faced the same problem, I would like to hear his solution too.

Comment: this is very helpful, I was having the same problem since a very long time but it never occurred me to check the pdf output